# I upgraded angular material to 7.2 and I want to use badge feature

Tags: angular, angular-material

I upgraded angular material to 7.2 and I want to use badge feature but it is not shown in my page. node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatBadgeModule'.

Answer (score 0):

As error says import 'MatBadgeModule' in app.module.ts

```
  import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';

   @NgModule({
      imports: [                 
     MatBadgeModule,
  ]
```